# haskell stack won't install dates

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

In a standalone module I'm using the dates package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dates installed via cabal and it works fine. But a problem emerges when I try to make a small package out of this module using stack. The dates package is appropriately listed in dependencies and all but it doesn't work. When I try to manually install the package using stack in the project sandbox, I get the below error. Meanwhile I can install this package with cabal outside the stack sandbox without issues.

VERSIONS IN THE SANDBOX:
ghc-8.4.3
stack-1.7.1

SYSTEM VERSIONS:
ghc-8.0.2
cabal-1.24.0.2 (compiled 1.24.2.0)

error message:

```
Configuring dates-0.2.2.1...
Preprocessing library for dates-0.2.2.1..
Building library for dates-0.2.2.1..
[1 of 4] Compiling Data.Dates.Internal ( Data/Dates/Internal.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/Data/Dates/Internal.o )
[2 of 4] Compiling Data.Dates.Types ( Data/Dates/Types.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/Data/Dates/Types.o )

/tmp/stack16211/dates-0.2.2.1/Data/Dates/Types.hs:62:10: error:
    • No instance for (Semigroup DateTime)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid DateTime’
   |
62 | instance Monoid DateTime where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This is strictly a result of different versions of ghc. Newer versions of ghc use a version of base that makes Semigroup a superclass of Monoid.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I needed to change the resolver in the stack.yaml file to an older version (lts-8.24) which would enforce the use of ghc-8.0.2. Using

stack --resolver ghc-8.0.2 setup/build

did not prevent stack from using the latest ghc version when I did

stack exec blah-exe

which raised the conflict.